# Symfony 4 + SonataAdminBundle composer install Gd not installed error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I am trying to make composer install in my Symfony 4 project with Sonata Admin Bundle. But still getting this error and it drives me mad[image]. I can't find any information :/ do you have any adivces or answer?

Thank you :)

Comment: Looks like gd is not installed. But you give absolutely no details on your setup. How do you run PHP? Are you using symfony serv? Are you using containers? Are you using some kind of MAMP, XAMP, WAMP... ?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using XAMP or similar on Windows OS because you have a `C:/[..]` path in the error message.

You need to **enable** the PHP [gd extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) (used for image processing) to get rid of the error.

> Gd not installed

Search for your `php.ini` configuration file, look for `"extension=gd2"` and uncomment it.

The path for XAMP is  `<xampp_dir>/php/php.ini`.

Eventually there are multiple `php.ini` files i.e. one for the PHP CLI and another one used by your webserver. Enable the extension in all of them.

Restart your webserver (likely apache) afterwards.